# Java i/o speed less than python i/o while printing an array

Tags: python, java, performance, array, time-limit-exceeded

**Motivation:** I was solving an array based i/o problem and encountered Time Limit Errors, it was later found that the code for java ran roughly `10x` slower than the python implementation.

**Question**: I would like to know which part of my code failed in the latter implementation (in Java) given that the algorithmic complexity for both the codes is the same. And what should I use in order to avoid it.

---

The problem is from https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/codemonk/ and a direct link doesn't exist.

Given problem abstract: If an indexed array `arr` is given, print the contents of the array whose index is shifted by a constant.

Example:

```
let arr=1,2,3,4
then arr shift 3 towards right means
2,3,4,1
```

Input format:

- first line: number of test cases
- for each test case:

  - first line contains n,k where n represents number of elements and k represents the shifting
  - the second line contains the elements of the array

Here is my *fast* python code

```py
from sys import stdin
t= int(input())
for i in range(t):
    n,k=list(map(int,input().split()))
    a=list(map(int,stdin.readline().split()))
    for i in range(n):
        print(a[(i-k)%n],end=" ")
    print("\n")
```

Here are the results:

[image: result].

Now, I wrote another solution in Java

```java
//imports for BufferedReader
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

//import for Scanner and other utility classes
import java.util.*;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        while(t-->0){
            String[] nk = input.readLine().split(" ");
            int n = Integer.parseInt(nk[0]);
            int k = Integer.parseInt(nk[1]);
            String [] arr = input.readLine().split(" ");
            for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
                System.out.printf("%s ",arr[(i-k%arr.length+arr.length)%(arr.length)]);
            }
            System.out.printf("%n");
       }
    }
}
```

And here are the results:

[image: results].

Comment: The standard comment/answer for performance questions: get yourself a decent profiler to find out what method call consumes the majority of time. I wouldn't be surprised to see some `Scanner` methods making the hot spots.

Comment: How `Scanner s` is used at all here?

Comment: `i-k%arr.length+arr.length` is vulnerable to integer overflow. That _may_ explain timeouts.

Comment: @vnp Oh, that is unnecessary here, although removing it didnt make a difference

Comment: @vnp pretty sure it isn't an overflow ...The time required for the failed test case is 3 seconds (tested on tio.run)...I cannot share the link, it is too long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Python Code

- [PEP-8](https://pep8.org/) recommends

  - a space around binary operators like `=`.
  - a space after commas (`n, k = …`)
  - using the throw away variable (`_`) for loops which do not need the loop index for anything (`for _ in range(t):`)
- the `list(…)` is unnecessary in the assignment to `n,k`
- the `map(int, …)` is unnecessary for the `a` array, as you are simply parroting the values back out.
- there is no need to use `stdin.readline()`, you could simply use `input()` like the previous lines.
- one-letter variables should not be used unless it is very clear what that variable name means.  `n` and `k` are from the problem statement, so are ok.  `t`, on the other hand, is very obfuscating.

Improved (readability & speed) code:

```py
num_tests = int(input())
for _ in range(num_tests):
    n, k = map(int, input().split())
    arr = input().split()
    for i in range(n):
        print(arr[(i-k) % n], end=' ')
    print("\n")
```

## Java Code

- `Scanner s` is unused.
- `t` is an obfuscating variable name
- try-with-resources should be used to ensure the `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader` are properly closed.
- `n` should be the array length, why use `arr.length`?

Performance issues:

- Double module operation: `(i-k%arr.length+arr.length)%(arr.length)`.  `-k%arr.length+arr.length` is a constant.  You could move that computation out of the loop.  Or, if `k` is always in `0 <= k <= n`, simply use `(i-k+n)%n`.
- `printf("%s ")` may be slowing your program down by creating a brand new string combining the arr element and a space.  Using `System.out.print(arr[(i-k+n)%n]); System.out.print(' ');` may be faster.

And the number 1 performance issue …

[`String[] String::split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

… you are using the Regular Expression engine to split the string into words!

Comment: I'll try these out, by the way, what method should I use instead of split? i was looking at the Reader class when I found that split is the updated method

Comment: Now, after [updating](https://tio.run/##hZA/T8MwEMX3fAoLqZJDlajMAQYQQyUmylY6mObaXpOcLdtpQaifPZxboGka4Jbzn/fe/ey12qhEG6B1XjQNVkZbL9Z8mKJO7@rFAizkT6BysFnUuR6Tqf3EW1BVn6L2WKaXWRTNS@WceAbn7/erj0hwmfq1xLlwXnluG425qBSS5ECkpVB26aYzEQu/snrrxMPbHIxHTV/2UKd8AgOPuBEE286VDEdnuHLy7jxUKVIcZz@hSF6ElDF5WIJNjbIOeCP38Snb80ckkG3PdoUlSJ8kt6P4iBfq8Bp@CBWc2Y1InSnRywtxwWEnvkBBfRRUTEez1uhvcfGL@KorDsJiQFkPpmBOZe1/oG3jQlsZxiObRhm3a8bmPhx2PmI/5fDfmqMNz/OSh00lJsWQ4oGkuIva6zln2EV/G16o5TiKo8N2FzXNJw) I fail only [1 test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmCOm.png)...thanks!

Comment: Also using printf("%n") to output A newline instead of println() is a bit wasteful. Before we had the split(Strign) method we had to use StringTokenizer for splitting strings.

Comment: [`StringUtils.split(str, ' ')`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split-java.lang.String-char-) would be a great option, if you can use the Apache commons libraries.  Failing that, you might have to roll your own ... or rethink the problem and come up with a different solution that doesn't require splitting the input into `n` tokens.

Comment: StringUtils is unfortunately not supported on the platform . . . given that it's because of the regex based input splitting, I think I should linear search and find partitions...then use substrings